# Hiding an individual cell in JTable depending on model value

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, abstracttablemodel

I have a JTable showing values from a model allowing integer values 0, 1 and 2. The values are shown in a 9 by 9 grid (like a sudoku game board).

**My question is:** How do I hide the zero values from the GUI?

That is, in the table cells that has a model value of zero, I dont want the GUI to show any value. The model must however contain the zero value due to calculations being done.

I have tried to use a DefaultTableCellRenderer and setting the cell component to invisible by using setVisible(true) (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598032/hiding-a-particular-cell-grid-in-jtable)), but I get no result.

I have managed to use a DefaultTableCellRenderer to toggle any cell's background color depending on the model state (if a cell is considered "negative"). **I do want to keep the background color visible**.

I am a bit new to java, so maybe this is just an update issue?

Here is my DefaultTableCellRenderer:

```
private static class GameTableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
        boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
            table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        GameModel model = (GameModel) table.getModel();

        if(model.isNegative(row, column))
            c.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        else
            c.setBackground(Color.white);

        if(model.getAbsoluteValueAt(row, column) == 0)
            c.setVisible(false);
        else
            c.setVisible(true);

        return c;
    }
}
```

The "getAbsoluteValueAt" method returns an integer 0, 1 or 2. The change of background color works perfectly fine.

My model extends AbstractTableModel, and the JTable uses the renderer like this:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(int.class, renderer);
```

I hope this information is enough to explain my problem and the efforts I so far have put in. Please ask for more information and I will provide it.

Thank you in advance. /Fredrik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making the component invisible, set its text to the empty string:

```
if (model.getAbsoluteValueAt(row, column) == 0) {
    ((JLabel) c).setText("");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect! I will use this solution!

Comment: You could also return a new empty component, such as a JTextField

Comment: Returning a new component every time is extremely inefficient. Swing uses the flyweight pattern for its renderers precisely to avoid that. And a JLabel is a better choice than a JTextField, so why not use the default renderer?

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use the following:

```
 if(model.getAbsoluteValueAt(row, column) == 0)
        c.setForeground(c.getBackground());
    else
        c.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works just as good as the accepted solution! I ended up with JB Nizet's answer since it is shorter :-)